# How can I get a mat Autocomplete to open when clicked?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I have a mat-autocomplete that holds a list of countries loaded from a json file, but the panel will only open after typing in a letter. After clicking away, it will open again as normal. But for some reason, the first time I have to type in something for any options to appear. I've tried using the isOpen boolean but no luck

mat-autocomplete

```
  <mat-form-field a>
    <mat-label>Region</mat-label>
    <input
      type="text"
      aria-label="Region"
      matInput
      required="true"
      [formControl]="regionForm"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />

    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredJSONDataOptions | async"
        [value]="option.name"
      >
        {{ option.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

.ts

```
  data: any;
  error: any;
  status: string;
  private subs = new Subscription();
  options: Regions[] = [];
  filteredJSONDataOptions: Observable<any[]>;
  regionForm = new FormControl();
  ...

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.filteredJSONDataOptions = this.regionForm.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this.json_data_filter(value))
    );

    this.subs.add(
      this.regionsSv.getRegions().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.options = data;
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could forced it to open when clicking the input programmatically like the following:

**html**

```html
 <input
   #myInput="matAutocompleteTrigger"
   type="text"
   aria-label="Region"
   matInput
   required="true"
   (click)="onClick(myInput); $event.stopPropagation()"
   [formControl]="regionForm"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
```

**ts**

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  // ....

  onClick(trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger): void {
    trigger.openPanel();
  }
}
```

Or without using a function, you could just open it in the template directly:

```html
 <input
   #myInput="matAutocompleteTrigger"
   type="text"
   aria-label="Region"
   matInput
   required="true"
   (click)="myInput.openPanel(); $event.stopPropagation()"
   [formControl]="regionForm"
   [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
```

You also have the option to `closePanel` using the trigger this way